# Is there a Fast Infoset implementation for Python?

Tags: python, xml, fastinfoset

I've seen libraries for C++ and Java, but no Python.

Comment: Would be helpful if you would tell us, what you actually want to do. If you want an answer, it's not my job to figure out what "fast infoset" really means.

Comment: @Achim, if you don't know what a "fast infoset" is, this question is not for you. :) (FYI, Fast Infoset is a standardized binary serialization of XML Infosets designed to be faster to parse and smaller to store.) I am not aware of any Python implementation. It's very enterprisey-flavored tech, so I kind of doubt it.

Comment: Most Pythonistas would prefer to stay as far away from XML as possible :)

Comment: Are any of the libraries you've seen open-source? I'd guess there are very few (or quite possibly none). If there is one, have you considered generating your own python bindings for it using, e.g. [swig](http://www.swig.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

The GlassFish [Fast Infoset Project](http://fi.java.net/) is open source.  But it is Java-based and thus couldn't be used via SWIG in Python.  But you could presumably use it with Python code via Jython.